# How to create a race situation between two threads in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, junit

I want to test a synchronized method that serves as an Id counter. In order to test the uniqueness of the IDs returned by the given method, I want to create a *race situation* between two threads who would make a call to the given method *at the same time*. How may I achieve that please?

```
class Counter{
    private static int nextId = 1;
    public static synchronized int nextId() {
        int id = nextId;
        nextId += 1;
        return id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to create a race condition on the posted code.
The mutable shared state is the private static `nextId` variable,
and it is guarded by the intrinsic lock of the class instance.
No two threads can enter the synchronized `nextId` method,
therefore a race condition is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to create two threads and have them get new ids from your Counter class:

```
Thread t1= new Thread(){
    public void run(){
      for(int i=0; i<1000; i++){
          System.out.println("T1: "+Counter.nextId());
      }
    }
  }

  t1.start();

Thread t2= new Thread(){
    public void run(){
      for(int i=0; i<1000; i++){
          System.out.println("T2: "+Counter.nextId());
      }
    }
  }

  t2.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

this will generate race conditions .run this program several times .it will give different results at the end each time at most of the time.this will work only with java version 1.8 or 1.8 + .for java versions below 1.8 use Runnable anonymous class instead lambda expressions .

```
       public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(()-> {
            Random rand = new Random();
            for(int i=0;i<1000;i++) {
                System.out.println(Counter.nextId());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(rand.nextInt(10));
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();

        new Thread(()-> {
            Random rand = new Random();
            for(int i=0;i<1000;i++) {
                System.out.println(Counter.nextId());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(rand.nextInt(10));
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
class Counter{
private static int nextId = 1;
public static  int nextId() {
    int id = nextId;
    nextId += 1;
    return id;
 }
}
```